# Command ignored within a method `new`

Tags: ruby, class

I am trying to define and call a function `new`:

```
module Me
  class Bobkat
    def new()
      puts "Kernel.caller()[0].to_s() is " << Kernel.caller()[0].to_s()
      initialize()
    end
    def initialize
      return self
    end
  end
end

Me::Bobkat.new()
```

It ignores the `puts` command. I was wondering why it does that. Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, the [default implementation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Class.html#method-i-new) calls `allocate` to create a new object, invokes the object's `initialize` method (passing any arguments) and returns the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to override new method, here you are:

```
module Me
  class Bobkat
    class << self
        def new(*args)
          puts "Kernel.caller()[0].to_s() is " << Kernel.caller()[0].to_s()
          super
        end
    end
  end
end

Me::Bobkat.new
```

Comment: Why so insanely complicated? What's wrong with just calling `super` instead of all that `alias_method` dance?

Comment: Insanely complicated is only vs. the alternatives... How is it done vs. the alternatives? Do you know of a simpler coding, using other languages? I hope that not starting a holy war here...

Comment: @user1134991 I guess Jörg didn't mean to start a "holy war" (whatever it may be in this context) but to point out your code is more complicated than it could be.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I agree with you, guys. I don't understand why I decide to use alias method instead of super call:) Answer has been updated

Comment: Clarification: This `alias_method` thing is an anti-pattern that was popularized by Ruby on Rails. There are better methods to achieve what it does, namely obtaining an `UnboundMethod` instance for the method to be overwritten and closing over that variable in the body of the overwriting method, `bind`ing it to `self` and `call`ing the resulting `Method` object. And as of Ruby 2.0, we have `Module#prepend`, which makes *both* those methods obsolete and replaces them with simple inheritance. However, in this specific case, *none* of that is necessary, because it's not monkeypatching anyway.

Comment: @SergeiStralenia to define a class method, you can just write `def self.new(*)` instead of opening the singleton class via `class << self`

Answer (score 6):

If you mean by "It ignores the puts command" the fact that the `puts` inside `Me::Bobkat#new` is not executed, that is because you never called `Me::Bobkat#new`. If you thought you have called it by doing `Me::Bobkat.new`, that is wrong. `Me::Bobkat#new` (instance method) and `Me::Bobkat.new` (class method) are different.

Comment: O.K. How is the class method defined? that is, I did not explicitly define it, and it got called...
Thanks.

Comment: Class method `new` is defined by default. It is always there (unless you undefine it). If you want to override it, then do `def self.new`.

Comment: @user1134991: That's not unusual. There are plenty of methods in Ruby's core library provided for you that you don't have to write yourself. For example, `String#gsub`, `Fixnum#+`, `Array#<<`, `Hash#[]`, `Kernel#puts`, `Kernel#require`, `Module#attr_accessor`, and many others. You are using no less than 5 different methods in your code that you didn't define explicitly … why would `new` be special? `Class#new` is a method like any other.